# URLRewrite - What is the regular expression pattern that match with this URL

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I would like to know the pattern for this:
http://desarrollo.test.com.mx/varSTATIC/fe/loquesea/mi-pagina.html

Im using URL Rewrite because i want to redirect this URL to:
http://otro.dominio.com/loquesea/mi-pagina.html

Then I need a pattern to match with an URL that contains "varSTATIC".

Please!! help!!!

Tnks!

Comment: What have you tried? What are you using (.htaccess)? This is ["good enough"](http://regex101.com/r/rF0iD1) given the available information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the pattern is more complex than just "contains varSTATIC". It seems you want to actually replace "varSTATIC/fe/loquesea" with just "loquesea".

So the pattern would be "varSTATIC/fe/loquesea/*" if you use wildcards and the Redirected URL would be loquesea/{R:1}